# adding attachments to the orders

Tags: shopify

I need to write an application that allows buyers to attach documents to their orders.

I am new to shopify and I have no idea how this should function.

I need to figure out how to add my custom functionality to the product details view that is shown when the user clicks on a product when visiting a store. Then I need to figure out how to attach to the order the document that the user selects.

If someone would at least point me in the right direction, I would appreciate that.

I know it is a broad question, I do not even know how to phrase it properly because my understanding of shopify infrastructure is so limited. Yes, I have read the development samples and API docs but for me they were lacking what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify recently added the ability to upload files as attachments to the cart line items. Take a look here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Line_Item_Properties#File_attachments

The uploaded file is stored in the CDN, and you can access it via liquid in your cart template and email notifications:

```
{% for p in item.properties %}{% unless p.last == blank %}
    {{ p.first }}:
    {% if p.last contains '/uploads/' %}
        <a href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ p.last }}
    {% endif %}
    <br />
{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
```

Note also that different file sizes are created per http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_img_url#Image_sizes